# How to extract a specific string using perl?

Tags: perl

I have set of strings say "-f /path/filename1.f", "-f $path/filename2.f", etc in a single file file.f I want to read file.f and extract /path/filename1.f, $path/filename2.f, etc in another file.
I tried finding solution online but it looks like a mess.

Is there any clean and simple solution there for these kind of simple pattern searching?

below is the requirement
Example,

```
file.f (input file to perl script)
-f /path/filename1.f
-f $path1/filename2.f
-f /path/filename3.f
-f $path2/filename4.f

outputfile.f
/path/filename1.f
$path1/filename2.f
/path/filename3.f
$path2/filename4.f
```

Basically I just want path string from the file.f

Comment: Could you please show a simple example of the input and the desired output, as well as the code you tried?

Comment: Hi @TimurShtatland I've just edited the question explaining desired output and input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some perl code to solve your problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fhi, "<", "file.f" or die "Error: $!";
open my $fho, ">", "output.f" or die "Error: $!";

while( <$fhi> ) {  # Read each line in $_ variable
    s/^-f //;      # Remove "-f " at the beginning of $_ 
    print $fho $_; # print $_ to output.f file
}
close $fhi;
close $fho;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using cut:

```
cut -f2 -d’ ‘ input_file > output_file
```

Or you can use Perl:

```
perl -lane ‘print $F[1]’ input_file > output_file
```

These solutions extract the second field of the input and print it.

Comment: It's working. But if I want to do it with perl then how can i achieve the same thing.
I've tried below code,

open(FILE,"<file.f");
  while(<FILE>) {
    if(/-f/s+(/w+)/) {
       print "$1";
     }
  }

but it's giving me the same strings without removing "-f  "

Comment: The second example I gave is actually a Perl one-liner. You can expand it into an actual Perl script with open, while, split, etc. As for the example in your comment, you probably need to change forward slash to backward slash in a few places where it means a special character or a character class, e.g. \s and \w . And change word character \w to non whitespace character \S.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the below solution -

Here everything after `-f` will be taken out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"<file.f"); 
while(<FILE>) 
    print "$1\n" if($_ =~ /^-f\s(.*)/);
}
```